# Updating EF Model from a View in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

I have at WPF app with a main window and some child windows. Using MVVM and EF. 
Here is a simplified overview over the Layers:

- MainView: here I have a GridView and a save button.
- MainViewmodel: with a property of ObservableCollection and a DelegateCommand for the save.
- ChildView: here I have a GridView and a save button.
- ChildViewmodel: with a property of ObservableCollection   and a DelegateCommand for the save.
- DataServices: with an EF Model providing Entitytype1 and Entitytype2

Here is a simplified overview over the Code (same for the Child views):

**XAML in MainView**

```
<Window>
   <UserControl.DataContext>
      <viewModel:MainViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <Grid>
       <GridView ItemsSource="{Binding MyEntityList}"/>
       <Button Content="Save" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"/>
   </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Code in MainViewmodel**

```
public ObservableCollection<Entitytype1> MyEntityList { get; set; }
private void LoadData()
{
   MyEntityList = new ObservableCollection<Entitytype1>(DataServices.GetData());
   OnPropertyChanged("MyEntityList");
}

SaveCommand = new DelegateCommand(Save);
private void Save()
{
   DataServices.SaveEntity1();
}
```

**Code in DataServices** 
I create the EF model when needed, I guess that having a EF hanging around the whole lifetime of the App. Is a bad idea?

```
public static IList<EntityType1> GetData()
{
   var list = new List<EntityType1>();
   using (var myEntitiesModel = new MyEntitiesModel())
   {
       list = myEntitiesModel.EntityType1s.ToList();
   }
   return list; 
}

public static SaveEntity1(?)
{
   ????
   myEntitiesModel.SaveChanges();
}
```

All this works fine, data is showing up in the grid on the Mainview.

Now for the question: How do I get data back to the database ?

When a user changes something in the grid it is changed in the ObservableCollection, using the Bindings, fine.

But how do I get the change back to the EF Model in the DataServices, and the back to the database, when the user clicks the save button on the view?

I guess the I could make a method in the DataServices the takes the ObservableCollection in and foreach over it and compare the items in it with all the items in the EF model to find the changed one.

But that don’t seem right, what is a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I create the EF model when needed, I guess that having a EF hanging around the whole lifetime of the App. Is a bad idea?

It depends. In an enterprise application the client application shouldn't have any dependency upon Entity Framework to begin with. You would typically communicate with the database using a data access layer (DAL) or a service or business layer which in turn calls the DAL behind the scenes. EF lives in the DAL only and the client application just calls some methods of the service layer to read and write data. It doesn't know anything about EF and there is no `DbContext` involved on the client side.

In a small application it might be okay to use a single `DbContext` for the lifetime of a view model or the entire application though. In this case you could create a single instance of your `MyEntitiesModel`, populate the `ObservableCollection<T>` with entities from this context and then call the `SaveChanges()` method of the same `DbContext` instance in the `Save()` method of your view model.

> I guess the I could make a method in the DataServices the takes the ObservableCollection in and foreach over it and compare the items in it with all the items in the EF model to find the changed one.
>
> But that don’t seem right, what is a better way?

You could also attach disconnected entities to a new `DbContext` instance and set the state of the attached entities. Please refer to the following blog post for more information about this: https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/05/30/generic-dal-using-entity-framework/

Comment: So having a Client with a View (MainView) and a DAL (DataServices) with a EF Model, how would you get the changed data from the View to the DAL?

Comment: The view model calls the service layer or the DAL in the Execute method of the command. And the view binds to the view model.

Comment: As I suggested: I guess the I could make a method in the DataServices the takes the ObservableCollection in and foreach over it and compare the items in it with all the items in the EF model to find the changed one.

Comment: It's either that or attached the entities to a new context as already explained. By the way, the service should take an IEnumerable or an IList rather than an ObservableCollection. An ObservableCollection belongs to the client side only.

Comment: Please remember to accept an answer and vote helpful answers up if your issue has been solved: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow

Answer (score 1):

I hardly recommend not to bind Models to your View. You should only bind ViewModels to your View. Have a look at the MVVM pattern.

When you load the data from the database via EF you'll get a list of items. If you iterate through this list you could create a ViewModel for each entry and each ViewModel could store the EF Model from which is was created. When saving your data you can iterate through your ViewModels and get the updated EF Model. When you've created a new ViewModel (without EF Model) you can create a new EF Model.

That's, in my opinion, a very clean approach and working for me since almost 10 years of developing WPF applications.

Comment: What do you mean by 'bind Models to you View'? I only bind a ViewModel  to  my View. And 'create a ViewModel for each entry' what do you mean?  Is it not one View - one Viewmodel? Like the name convention MainView – MainViewmodel. Or did I miss something, Can you please provide an eksample.

Comment: But your properties e.g. MyEntityList  contain Models and not ViewModels. That's what I meant. Would be better if your ViewModel which is DataContext of your View is using ViewModels, too.

Comment: I been reading a lot about MVVM, and it looks like its not all fixed rules. 
_ Some would say that exposing an entity directly is not pure MVVM since the entity is the model and exposing the model to the View is a bit naughty.
 Others say that getting the data into that entity is the model layer and the entity object is just a class., so it's no problem.
 This is one of those areas in MVVM which is perhaps somewhat grey._

Comment: The problem when binding a Model to a View ist that you have to put UI specific code into your Model like INotifyPropertyChanged. And you would get in trouble when implementing e.g. an undo function.